# complete dagrun and then disable dag

Tags: airflow

is there a way i can tell airflow to turn off the dag, but only after current dagrun has complete?

if i disable the dag halfway through a run, it will naturally stop processing the dag. however, when i resume it, it will continue where it left off. the state of that dagrun doesn't really matter to me, so i currently manually 'fail' the dagrun (by hand).

is there a way i can either fail the current (recent?) dagrun or allow the dagrun to finish then be disabled by command line and or through an API?

Comment: There is an ongoing issue for the same: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/22006. I think it resembles what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `catchup=False`in your DAG options (or set `catchup_by_default=False` in your `airflow.cfg`) you're going to disable *backfilling*. This means that the scheduler will run only the latest execution due for your DAG. If you turn off your DAG and turn on again, there's no way to stop Airflow from picking it up because that's what it's meant to do.

So I assume that your problem is with DAGs that are already scheduled and marked as `RUNNING`. In that case, what you can do is create another DAG responsible for "killing" the former, or simply keep it off until you need to run it again and put an `Operator` in the beginning of your DAG responsible for turning off previous executions that might still be marked as `RUNNING`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure in what you are trying to do, but it seems to me that the DAG should run only once.

So you could pass

`schedule_interval = '@once'`

in `default_args`.